# InstallShield - Reinstallmode is defaulting to 'vomus'

Tags: windows-installer, installation, upgrade, installshield, reinstall

We have BasicMSI installer project, and we have set the reinstallmode and reinstallmodetext to vemus(also tried emus). But the actual command line parameter passed is `REINSTALLMODE=vomus`.

We are versioning DLL files in our project but we also have too many unversioned files(resources...) so we would like to avoid using 'Always overwrite' on them and use reinstallmode vemus instead.

I've also created fresh test BasicMSI project that will only install one file and basically only added `Reinstallmode = vemus` and also changed `reinstallmodetext = vemus`.

1. installed test project first time
2. increment product version in installshield project and build it
3. upgrade => in install log i still see `REINSTALLMODE=vomus`

I would really appreciate any help, since i was unable to find any solution online so far.

Comment: Can't you do a major upgrade with RemoveExistingProducts sequenced immediately after InstallInitialize? That would uninstall all the old product then install the new, no overwrite issues.  It's not clear from your question exactly how you are doing the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sense to set up these unversioned files as [companion files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367997)? While vemus isn't as risky as vamus it's still unusual. And I agree that it's better to avoid the fake version information that "always overwrite" requires.

Here are the steps for [configuring companion files in InstallShield](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/CompanionFiles.htm):

- Add both files, making sure to note the Key for the versioned file; you can find the Key in the component's view, among other places
- Edit the properties of the unversioned file
- Override its version to match the Key value for the versioned file

If you have a lot of these to set up, it may be easier to do so in the Direct Editor > File table.